# Loading a PHP page into a HTML div

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am currently trying to create a portion of my website that fetches a mySQL table. I wrote the php to fetch the data, create a table, and print out the table in a separate php file named `display.php`. Now i am trying to load it into a div on my html page but for some reason it is not working. I am using XAMPP and php is working as my login page works. Here is the code:

HTML: (I have tried both include and require)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="display" class="myCustom1">
       <?php require('display.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="display" class="myCustom1">
        <?php include("display.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP: (if i run just the php page it creates the table)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test";
$password = "test";
$database = "data1";

//create connection & access DB
$connect = mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$database"); 

//if error, display error
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM data1enter");

echo 
"
    <table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Song</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    </tr>
";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['song'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['author'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: what is the name of your html file , is it html file or php file ? Also check the include path

Comment: What error you are getting? Try enabling PHP error reporting..

Comment: Note: There's no reason to have things like `"$servername"` when `$servername` will do.

Comment: @Poria my html file is named index.html and my php is display.php

Comment: @Sid how do i enable the error reporting?

Comment: How come you are using <?php tags in html file.. rename it to index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `<?php ?>` tags in the html file, Change the extension of the file containing the below code to `.php` from `.html` and you will be able to use include function.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="display" class="myCustom1">
       <?php require('display.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="display" class="myCustom1">
        <?php include("display.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also make sure the include path is correct.
Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! I didn't know the file had to be saved as a .php file. It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Display should be blade template ..

```
@include('display')
```

Give path to display template

Answer (score -1):

Just put the php in a function. Then you can do this:

```
<html> 
<body>
<?php require_once('display.php'); ?>
<div id="display" class="myCustom1">
<?php render(); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php
function render() 
{
     //YOUR PHP CODE
}
?>
```

Comment: so there's no way to keep the two files separate?

Comment: also just tried that and it just output the code directly after `$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM data1enter");` in the php code above